# Receiving error stating "name.split is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, split, react-router

I'm attempting to parse a single user input but [it's throwing an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTsmc.png) stating:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): name.split is not a function

When I attempt to search the name of a creator, like `Frank Miller` for example it throws that error.

```
class Creators extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      comics: []
    };
  }

  byCreator = async name => {
    var names = name.split(" ");
    var firstName = names[0];
    var lastName = names[1];
    await fetch(
      `https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/creators?firstName=${firstName}%20&lastName=${lastName}&apikey=117b458635106b9721749634b53fb07b`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        const creatorID = json.data.results[0].id;
        return fetch(
          `https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/comics?creators=${creatorID}&apikey=117b458635106b9721749634b53fb07b`,
          { cache: "force-cache" }
        );
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(d => this.setState({ comics: d.data.results }));
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="search"
            placeholder="creator"
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button onClick={this.byCreator}>Search</button>
        </div>

        <ul>
          {this.state.comics.map(c => (
            <li key={c.id}>
              <p> {c.title} </p>
              <p> {c.description} </p>
              <img src={c.thumbnail.path + "." + c.thumbnail.extension} />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include all code needed to reproduce the problem and the error in text format instead of linking to external images.

Comment: My apologies, this is my first post here so I'm still trying to figure things out.

Comment: byCreator is event handler function of a button but you are expecting name in byCreator function which is wrong. There is no name, first name and last name in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a handle to button click and the call byCreator passing a value to name parameter:

```
handleClick: event => {
    const valueForNameParam = this.state.value; // or any other string
    this.byCreator(valueForNameParam);
}
```

then you have to bind your new function (and the existing handleChange function) to the instance of the object in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        comics: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

At last, you have to change the bind on the button click event from byCreator function to handleClick function:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Search</button>
```

If you do this changes the reported error will be solved.